# PyInstaller : 'no module named os.path'

Tags: python, matplotlib, module, compilation, pyinstaller

I'm trying to compile a code named 'interface.py' with PyInstaller. Everything goes fine during the compilation but when I try to launch 'interface.exe' I get this error:

```
    [INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\Samuel\.kivy\logs\kivy_18-01-26_19.txt
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\Samuel\.kivy\logs\kivy_18-01-26_19.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.10.0
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v2.7.14 (v2.7.14:84471935ed, Sep 16 2017, 20:19:30) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 194 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_gif (img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\Samuel\Documents\PycharmProjects\Zernik\interface.py", line 8, in <module>
     from kivy.garden.matplotlib.backend_kivyagg import FigureCanvasKivyAgg
   File "c:\users\samuel\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-pp0wwt\pyinstaller\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 396, in load_module
   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\kivy\garden\__init__.py", line 68, in <module>
     from os.path import dirname, join, realpath, exists, abspath
   File "c:\users\samuel\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-pp0wwt\pyinstaller\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 161, in load_module
   File "c:\users\samuel\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-pp0wwt\pyinstaller\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 396, in load_module
   File "C:\Python27\lib\os.py", line 120, in <module>
     from os.path import (curdir, pardir, sep, pathsep, defpath, extsep, altsep,
 ImportError: No module named path
[11308] Failed to execute script interface
```

In 'interface.py' these are the modules I import:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.filechooser import FileChooserIconView
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.garden.matplotlib.backend_kivyagg import FigureCanvasKivyAgg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import opticspy.zernike as oz
import numpy as np
import xlrd
```

And I use matplotlib in opticspy.zernike.
I tried to import os.path in 'interface.py' but it didn't worked.
I think the error comes from the kivy.garden.matplotlib module because before I use it, it worked fine.

Do you know what I'm doing wrong ?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Try import os as a whole.

Comment: It is not working either

Comment: With what Error?

Comment: Exactly the same error, I tried to import os in 'interface.py', I also tried to import sys. In my .spec file I tried to add os, sys, and kivy.garden but it didn't changed anything.

Comment: Print sys.path before importing os  and tell me your results,also are you using both python 2,3 on your pc and what are your operating system?

Comment: I'm on windows 10 64bit, and I had both python 2 and 3 but recently I uninstalled python 3 (it was python3 with anaconda so I think that python3 has been well uninstalled).

Comment: Import sys before all modules and before importing os, print(sys.path) and check what it prints.If you can't even import sys something it's wrong with your python installation or you have mixd installations in your pc.

Comment: By printing sys.path I get this :   ['C:\\Users\\Samuel\\DOCUME~1\\PYCHAR~1\\Zernik\\dist\\INTERF~1']

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I solved my problem by completely uninstall python from my computer. Then I re-install python 3 (rather than python 2 that I had) and now it works. It seems that python 3 works better than python 2 for this.

Thank you for your help. I hope you didn't spent too much time on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but i can't write at comments.
Try :
    sys.path.insert(0,'C:/Python27/lib') 
before importing os as it seems this module  somehow changes your sys path, or if it still fails try import os before all other modules.
Also you can print sys.path at another test script to see witch is the correct sys.path and add it.
Hope this helps.